# Springboot scheduler - pause/resume task

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, file-upload, scheduler

I've a Springboot scheduler (annotated with @Scheduled) which uploads a file to Amazon S3 bucket. Now, ask is to be able to pause/resume upload on demand.

My understanding is that since this scheduler uploads file in a separate thread, it may not be possible to achieve pause/resume functionality.

I've already looked into some options that provide client side solution using JS libraries/packages or AWS SDK but it requires complete rewrite of existing functionality. So, What are other possible options that can be implemented from backend with less amount of change including UI to pause/resume/track upload, if that's possible?

Comment: You can't pause/resume a task scheduled with annotations. But you can if you create the task programmatically https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I looked into the tutorial and other Classes/APIs its referring to but didn't find anything that would help with  pause/resume kind of functionality. please do let me know further pointers, if I missed any.